# How to allow selection of only one property with google analytics API

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to "embed" google analytic reports in to my web page and so far i was following this [ga-dev-tools.appspot.com](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/) tutorials/documentations. This is my result right now...
[image]

The problem is that i don't wan't to display all properties (strikeout options on image) and i wan't to display only property of current page so i need to find out how to allow displaying only one property.

So this is my code so far

```
<h2>Sessions</h2>
<p>Last 30 days</p>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<div id="view-selector-container"></div>
    
<script>
    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
        /**
         * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
         * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
         * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
         */
        gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
            container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
            clientid: '<MyClientId>'
        });

        /**
         * Create a new ViewSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
         * element with the id "view-selector-container".
         */
        var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
            container: 'view-selector-container',
        });

        // Render the view selector to the page.
        viewSelector.execute();

        /**
         * Create a new DataChart instance with the given query parameters
         * and Google chart options. It will be rendered inside an element
         * with the id "chart-container".
         */
        var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            query: {
                metrics: 'ga:sessions',
                dimensions: 'ga:date',
                'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                'end-date': 'yesterday'
            },
            chart: {
                container: 'chart-container',
                type: 'LINE',
                options: {
                    width: '100%'
                }
            }
        });

        /**
         * Render the dataChart on the page whenever a new view is selected.
         */
        viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
            dataChart.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
        });
    });
</script>
```

So guy is it possible to add some param somewhere to display/get data for only one property?
If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your use case. If you mean for convenience, so that the user has not go through a list to find the relevant view, you can build a select field combo manually that only has the relevant ids hardcoded (and then you set them as parameter in the dataChart set method before you execute the query just like you do with the output from the viewSelector).

If you mean as some kind of security mechanism then no (since the users will have access to their properties in any case, plus this is Javascript where you can manipulate the calls in the browser).

Comment: Super! Thx for the tip!